# How to tell cgo to mark a []byte for garbage collection?

Tags: go, garbage-collection, cgo

I am calling the following C function from Go:

```
char *my_read(int dd) {
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUF_SUZE);

    if (!buf) {
        return NULL; // cannot allocate memory
    }

    while (read(dd, buf, BUF_SIZE) < 0) {
        if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EINTR) {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    return buf;
}
```

My Go code looks like this:

```
//#include "hci_cgo.h"
import "C"

func MyRead(dd int) ([]byte, error) {
    data, err := C.my_read(dd)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if data == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("my_read: cannot allocate memory")
    }
    // Here we create a Go slice of the data, but the C buffer is kept forever:
    return C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(data), C.BUF_SIZE)
}
```

How should I modify `MyRead` (or the corresponding C code) to free the allocated buffer before returning from `MyRead`?

Alternatively, can I re-use a single buffer in C, and thus avoid allocation altogether, and create Go `[]byte` copies of the data after `C.my_read(…)` returns? If so, I could put a mutex in `MyRead` to ensure sequential calls to `C.my_read(…)`, but how do I copy the C buffer to Go so that the GC would know about it?

Comment: It looks from https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/cgo like `GoBytes` doesn't copy any data. That would mean you *can't* free the malloc'd buffer until you're done with it from Go; then you could call a `C.FreeReadBuf()` that talks to C `free`. If that won't do, consider making your C read into a buffer allocated from Go.

Comment: On your last question ("how do i copy?"), that'd just be `copiedBytes := append([]byte(nil), returnValueOfGoBytes...)`.

Comment: Thanks @twotwotwo, I somehow overlooked that `append` is the easy way to copy slices. However, your first suggestion (letting C copy to a buffer allocated from Go) seems the most foolproof way to go — no C allocations, nothing to `free`.

Comment: @AttilaO: no, allowing C to access a go slice is far from foolproof and should be avoided if possible. For example, inadvertently allowing the value to get GC'ed will cause a dangling pointer in C. Theres even talk of disallowing this altogether, or at least making it much more strict so that a compacting GC can be added. Just remember that Go knows *nothing* about what happens in the C code, and use proper memory management techniques in C as if it were a standalone program. (also, there's the `copy` built-in for copying bytes)